# How do I control where my Debian package files are installed?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, packages

I'm trying to create a debian packge of my PHP application and to upload to my PPA.
I've been reading through [the documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Complete#Binary_and_Source_Packages) but I am missing one important point:

How do I control in which **directory** my web-app gets installed to and which files are included? The PHP app does not need any compilation, so it is distributed in source form.

Steps already done:

- Created a `name-1.0.tar.gz` which contains all the source
- `dh_make` to setup the environment (although I`m not sure which type i need in my case? (single binary, multiple binary, library) as I don`t have a "binary" but just php script files).
- Edited the `copyright/control/changelog` files.

  - After all that, I invoke `dpkg-buildpackage -S -rfakeroot` and the package is created.

**Problem:** The package has been created, but there are no files within it. I would like to install my web-app to `/var/www/`, so how do I get the packaging system to include all my web-app's `*.php` files and install it to `/var/www`?

I usually build Debian files with **dpkg -b** where it simple "maps" alle directories to the according file system. So I usually have the following tree:

- DEBIAN

  - control
- var

  - www

    - myproject
    - .... all files and subfolders

The package installs in /var/www/myproject/ and everything is fine.

But as I need to publish now to my PPA (which requires signing, hashing etc.), I need to follow the packaging guide with the previously mentioned problems.

Comment: As a side note you MUST NOT install files to /var/www but rather put them in /usr/share/yourapp/ as phpmyadmin does (have a look at their deb file) and supply an apache vhost config file in /etc/yourapp/.

Answer (score 1):

As for paths, I can tell you PPAs get extracted to /, and it's highly recommended to use autotools regardless of language of the source, so when a user performs the configure/make/make install the scripts take care of where to put everything.

I do not know why you are getting an empty package. Perhaps there is a log of the tools you are using somewhere? You'd like to think there's explicit output somewhere.